# How do we add the element of class "Course" to our vector? java

Tags: java

How do we add the element of class "Course" to our vector?

```
list.addElement(new Course(code, name));
```

Part of the class "course":

```
public class Course
{
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Course(String theCode, String theName)
    {
    code = theCode;
    name = theName;
    }
```

More of the code:

```
    public void load() throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                           (new FileReader("courses.txt"));

    String line = in.readLine();


       while(line != null)
       {
            String tokenline[] = line.split(" ");

            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line," ");

            line = in.readLine();



            int i = 1;

            while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    code = tokens.nextToken();
                }
                else if(i == 2)
                {
                    name = tokens.nextToken();
                }
                else
                {
                    name = name + " " + tokens.nextToken();
                }
                i=i+1;
            }

                        list.addElement(new Course(code, name));
       }

  }

 public void print()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i = i + 1)
    {
            System.out.println(list.elementAt(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: It should work fine. Do you have any compilation error? Please post a reproductible small example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You really should be using `List<Course>` instead of `Vector`

Comment: @ZouZou no compilation error but the output is not correct. We added more code, maybe you can help us now?

Comment: @rebeccaakk What do you mean by "output not correct"? I suggest you to use the debugger to see the what is the execution flow of your program.

Comment: @ZouZou We're trying to print every row of the vector, but nothing happends.

Comment: @rebeccaakk `System.out.println(list.elementAt(i));` this line will call the method toString of che class Course, if it is not overwritten in the class it will just print the address of the object. To see if the strings you're tokening are correct, you could print them and then check if something is wrong with the object Course.

Answer (score 0):

```
package rio;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class CourseHelper {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<Course> list = new ArrayList<Course>();

        try {
            load(list);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        print(list);
    }

    public static void load(List<Course> list) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("courses.txt"));

        String line = in.readLine();
        String code = null;
        String name = null;

        while (line != null) {
            String tokenline[] = line.split(" ");

            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

            line = in.readLine();

            int i = 1;

            while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    code = tokens.nextToken();
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    name = tokens.nextToken();
                } else {
                    name = name + " " + tokens.nextToken();
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }

            list.add(new Course(code, name));
        }

    }

    public static void print(List<Course> list) {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i = i + 1) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

    }
}

class Course {
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Course(String theCode, String theName) {
        code = theCode;
        name = theName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Course Code: " + code + " Name: " + name;
    }
}
```